# Lambda Syntax to Join Mutliple Reference Tables to Main Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have 3 tables:

- Users: (Id, FirstName, LastName, DepartmentId, LocationId)
- Departments: (Id, DepartmentName)
- Locations: (Id, LocationName)

How can I join the `Department.Id` to `User.DepartmentId` and `Location.Id` to `User.LocationId` using lambda expressions?

I'm stuck currently with 1 join. Tried to research on this, but the results I can see are related to many to many relationship.

```
var userJoin = _db.Users
                  .Join(_db.Departments, 
                        user => user.DepartmentId, 
                        dept=> dept.Id, 
                        (l, r) => new { l, r })
                  .Select(m => new UserModel()
                                   {
                                       // Map
                                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: If your model has properly defined navigation properties, the joins should be hidden behind those accesses and generated by EF on your behalf. You should rephrase your question to state the problem you are facing rather than the solution you want. Additionally, I think a department should have a location whether any users are associated with it or not. A user's location is not a department's location. What if there are two or more users with different locations? Which one do you pick for department's location then?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

**Using navigation [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)**. It would be easier and looks like that

```
context.Users.Include(x=>x.Department)
.Include(x=>x.Location)
.ToList()
```

**Using join**

```
context.Users.Join(context.Departments, x=>x.DepartmentId, x=>x.Id, (user, department) => new
            {
                User = user, 
                Department = department
            })
            .Join(context.Locations, x=>x.User.LocationId, x=>x.Id, (userDepartment, location) => new
            {
                User = userDepartment.User, 
                Department = userDepartment.Department,
                Location = location
            })
            .ToList()
```